# Django, handling m2m change signals over a model with multi ManyToManyField

Tags: django-models, django-signals, m2m

I have a model M contains three manytomanyfields(a,b,c) to three different models in django.

```
    class M (models.Model):
           name = models.CharField()
           a = models.ManyToManyField(A)
           b = models.ManyToManyField(B)
           c = models.ManyToManyField(C)
```

Now, I want to handle any changes on my model M and send an HttpRequest to an url correspondingly.
as you know in post-save signal of model M the values of attributes for a,b and c are not set yet because they will be set when saving model M has been finished.(the rule of ManyToManyField)

I write a single handler for my model to handle any changes(either create a new instance or update a field/fields)

```
    @receiver(post_save, sender=M)
    @receiver(m2m_changed, sender=M.a.through)
    @receiver(m2m_changed, sender=M.b.through)
    @receiver(m2m_changed, sender=M.c.through)
    def M_changes_handler(sender, **kwargs):
          is_instance_set_compeletly(kwargs['instance']):
              #send_and_HttpRequest(url, data = instance)


    def is_instance_set_compeletly(kwargs['instance']):
          if M.a.all() is not None and M.b.all() is not None and 
              M.c.all()is not None
             flag = True
          else:
             flag = False
          return flag
```

Now consider an update request (which changes all fields) on model M will send signals for all fields a,b and c; so three httpRequests would send to my sender with three different versions of instance! on the other hand when user just changes a field for example b of the model M this function will send only one httpRequest.

I want to handle this problem dynamically and just send one request per ANY TYPE of CHANGE on my model M. 
I was wondering if somebody could help me :)

*Note the code above is just a draft and may contains syntax error so ignore them ;)

Update: My problem solved!
The process of saving a model containing m2mfields is interesting!
First of all the fields of M which are not m2m fields type e.g. are char field, foreign key or etc. had been set before calling post_save. So in post_save their values are updated
Although m2mfields wont be set till the saving of the model would be finished. Then m2mchange signals called to set m2mfields
The only way to have an updated version of your model is to overriding form save in admin.py because the "form save" will be called after finishing all m2mfields have been set

Comment: Can you add an example how did you solve your issue?

Comment: I think you need to call all() on the related manager of the instance, not the class itself. because m2m relationships are instance specific, and it means each instance has its own related objects. can you try that? and if you have a solution would be nice to share with others to show how it works, so then everyone else can understand how to deal with it

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
For all stack-overflow users and Dear Blake Gibbs
If a model contains manytomany fields and you want to access all the data of a saved record, you cannot access those m2m fields because they will save after finishing the process of saving model(consider M in my example), then assign that Id to other self-created m2m table to bind that Id to m2m fields (e.g. A in my example). so overriding the save method of a model in admin.py does not work in this case.
I simply override the save function of my form in Forms.py

class MForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
        model = M          
        exclude = []
def save(self, commit=True):
    query = ""
    old_instance = super(MForm, self).save(commit=False)# if you need the old instance
```

#otherwise return super(MForm, self).save(commit=True)

```
    instance = super(MForm,self).save(commit=True)
```

in this case the "instance" is really saved completely and you can access m2m fields by using ".all()"

hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

you can hold previously instance of M and in post_save with new M  check field have changed according to that you can send request.

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately this doesnt work in my case because when an instance of model which contains m2mfields recieved by a post_save signal has the same value with the previous one till the m2mfields will be saved after post_save!

Answer (score 0):

In general: handling changes with signals in django is not recomended in cases of m2m fields or backwords forignKey, this is because:
By many to many - nither table changes, the table in the DB that changes is the table holding thier pk's that connect the two tables.
By backwords forignKey - the forign key could only be related to a instence that is created, not one that is not in the DB yet, and it goes to the db only when the save happens.
If you still want to use signals, to prevent calling twice the changes funtion, you could use `dispatch_uid`, and in a for loop in apps.py connect your signal to your model, this might be a easier solution then overriding the "forms save" in the `admin.py`